# How to transform the coordinate to the map when the kinect has been tilted

Tags: transforms, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am consider to put the kinect on the Turtlebot and tilt it up in order to detect the faces. But the depth measurement would be changed by that, so how to transform the kinect coordinate to the world coordinate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135316/how-to-transform-the-coordinate-to-the-map-when-the-kinect-has-been-tilted/) by [Jianyuan Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/11541/jianyuan-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you update the URDF of your Turtlebot to reflect the change, then any transformations using TF will automatically be updated. However, it should be noted that if you tilt the kinect, this will likely break navigation (if you are using that), since AMCL will likely not be able to localize.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jianyuan Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/11541/jianyuan-ma/) on 2014-03-03**:
I know it, I have another kinect to put above the turtlebot, the one for navigation would not be changed